# Видео зависает при перемотке

Tags: android, html5, google-chrome, видео

Здравствуйте!

Возникла проблема с html5 видео плеером в Android в новых версиях Google Chrome.

Видео стартует быстро, но если перематываешь, развернув на полный экран, оно зависает и не воспроизводится.

Плеер создается так:

```
<video controls="1" preload="metadata" name="media">
    <source src="http://site.ru/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Было выявлено, что если в атрибуте **preload** поставить значение **auto**, то все работает нормально.

**Вопрос:** нет ли другого решения, ибо полная предзагрузка ролика сильно нагрузит сервер с видео?

Хотелось бы обойтись вообще без предзагрузки или ограничиться метаданными.

В iOS и на ПК все нормально, проблема только в адроиде.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, и еще желательно добавьте к mp4 еще какой нибудь формат (можно переконвертировать `WebM`    `video/webm` или `Ogg`  `video/ogg`, вот пример:

```
<video width="600" height="440" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```